# How do I access form from ng-form if the form name is a variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

The following code works if formName is set to "myformName"

```
<ng-form="{{formName}}">
   is form dirty? : {{myformName.$dirty}}
   entire form object : {{myformName | json}}
</ng-form>
```

But of course we don't know the form name because we're using a variable.

How do I access form from ng-form using a variable form name and not using a hardcoded form name?

The following doesn't work:

```
<ng-form="{{formName}}">
   is form dirty? : {{myScope[myScope.formName].$dirty}}
   entire form object : {{myScope[myScope.formName] | json}}
</ng-form>
```

Comment: Try `this[formName]`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Please convert your comment into answer and I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Great! I wasn't entirely sure it would work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AngularJS templates, the current `$scope` may be referenced by `this`. With that in mind, you can use something like

```
{{this[formName].$dirty}}
```